# Dynamic Cell Ranges in Formula

Tags: vba, function, excel

I am having trouble creating a formula where a cell range in an input.

```
Function CellBefore(CellRange As String)

CellBefore = ActiveSheet.WorksheetFunction.Offset(CellRange, 0, 2).Value

End Function
```

Comment: change `As String` to `As Range`. Offset requires a Range Object as the first argument. Change `.Offset(CellRange)` to `.Offset(Range(CellRange)` will also work, but it's clunkier.

Comment: I changed the formula to the below and i still get #VALUE                        Function CellBefore(CellRange As Range)

CellBefore = ActiveSheet.WorksheetFunction.Offset(Range(CellRange), 0, 2).Value

End Function

Comment: If CellRange is a range @ScottHoltzman then the offset should be `.Offset(CellRange,..`  If you are passing a sting address then leave it a string and then what Scott said is true it needs to be `.Offset(Range(CellRange)`

Comment: I Assume for the String input, it would need to be =Cell("Address",A1) or something similar? I tried doing that and i'm still getting a #VALUE issue

Answer (score 2):

Apparently `.Offset` is not available as a worksheet function from within a macro. You can use the `Range.Offset` method:

```
Function CellBefore(CellRange As String)
    CellBefore = Range(CellRange).Offset.Value
End Function
```

or

```
Function CellBefore(CellRange As Range)
    CellBefore = CellRange.Offset(0, 2).Value
End Function
```